# How can I manage dual boot with Foreman?

Tags: kickstart, foreman

I have about 80 machines that need to boot both CentOS 7 (for most applications) and CentOS 6 (for one stubborn app). There seems to be very little documentation out there on getting Kickstart files that won't clobber each other; is there a guide or any pointers on installing two Linux OSes side-by-side with Kickstart?

The machines (due to our external DNS management) will need to have the same DNS name whichever flavour they boot, so am I going to have to use two Foreman instances to manage them?

It'll be a pain if the only way to do this is to manually put a second installation on each!

Comment: Does the "stubborn" app really need to run on every workstation or could you use it remotely on one central machine?

Comment: Other than that, I doubt that you'll have a lot of success with a kickstart-based install and would investigate methods to do some kind of image-based install.

Comment: Does the stubborn app _really_ need CentOS 6, or can you run it under 7 with backward compatibility libraries installed?

Comment: The power we'd need to throw at a single instance is staggering - something like 600 GB RAM - it will have to run locally, unfortunately, because 50+ simultaneous users.

Comment: It checks for 6 at launch, and the licence prohibits us from modifying that.

Comment: Why not run it in a VM?

Comment: I can investigate VMs, but as usual, not enough time to do everything :o) I can already do plenty of deployments with Foreman so it would save working out exactly how to automatically deploy and build 80 VMs!